# Chess Clock App that does not pause when put in the background?

Tags: chess-clocks, android

I am looking to track how much time I spent "working" and "not working". I would like to use a chess clock for this. When I go away from my desk, I hit the player 1's timer, and when I get back to work, I hit the player 2's timer.

I think I found some **Android** apps that could work nicely, but if I need to switch apps or lock the screen, they all pause. Is there any such app that runs in the background? I use Android.

Comment: A coworker uses something called "pomello" which seems very similar to what you're looking for.  As I personally haven't used it, I'm leaving this as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [pomello](http://www.pomelloapp.com/).

This isn't a timetracker really. It's more for those who practice the [pomodoro technique](http://pomodorotechnique.com/). It tracks the number of pomodoros you can achieve while allowing you to also tag disruptions and keep you focused until your break. I picked this particular one because it's integrated with trello. The integration allows it to tag your work items with the number of pomodoros you've done on that work item.

Comment: The "pomodoro technique" is a unit of work time of 25 minutes. you work for 25 minutes, then rest for 5 minutes. Every 3rd or 4th cycle, you break for 15 minutes. It's a well known time management technique.